# Getting DDR 400Mhz ram to run at 533Mhz

Tags: overclocking

Someone at the computer enthusiasts site "yelled" at me that this question belongs here.

I got my Dell Dimension 2400 to run at a FSB of 133Mhz! Yes, I plan to make a more in depth tutorial.

None of the DDR memory I have is fully stable. I tip my hat to Samsung and SKHynix for making ram that is half/mostly stable, but they still arn't stable.

Would increasing the voltage help? (I'm sure the voltage regulator for the ram is SOMEWHERE on the board. Probably not fixed either.)

Or is changing the memory timings the better option? (Apparently you can edit the SPD rom on ram sticks using "SPDTool". Probably malware lol.)

I might be able to overclock a McDonalds LCD game, but ram overclocking and timing just gives me a headache.

Or maybe the best option is to buy high end DDR ram from *somewhere.* Not sure if 133Mhz DDR is a thing.

Comment: A less than 20 year old Pentium4 isn't exactly a retro system nor are questions about RAM overclocking really on topic here. Even less as fitting faster RAM are still available new. Also, fasterCPU may result in more speed up (Note: 2.4 Ghz Prescot may be faaster than 2.8 due HTT, depending on OS and workload). If you really want to twiddle with existing RAM don't fear, there are plenty related sites an information for new(ish) mainstream systems like that out on the net.

Comment: Eh.... These things are getting there though. Now, regarding the overclocking part: Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

After running memtest86 and doing a quick stability check under linux, changing the timing data on the SPD is definitely AN option!

Using that "SPDTool" program, I changed the "SDRAM Cycle time at Max Supported CAS Latency" from 6ns (167Mhz) to 7ns (143Mhz).

"Minimum Clock Cycle at CLX-1" was changed from 7.5ns (133Mhz) to 8ns (125Mhz).

I'm sure I'm doing SOMETHING wrong, but it does work! Well, over and underclocking ram is notorious for being tricky. Making sure everything is stable is quite difficult.

Comment: Using things like electronics parts outside their rated specs means they don't have to work as expected or at all. Having an unstable system is kind of what you would expect, if the memory cells can't function with the timing you introduce, even if the memory chip bus could run overclocked. It might not be possible to slow down the timings to a level that makes the memory cells function stably, and by adding delays in the timing units available until it works might mean your bus is 133 MHz with so large delays that a 100 MHz bus with standard delays is faster. This can be calculated.

Comment: You are 100% right! But that IS the thrill of overclocking! Pushing stuff to their limits!

Answer (score 1):

Cool it. CMOS is faster at lower temperatures.

Comment: ROTFL - Lovely Answer:))

Comment: That IS true! Although, I think I'll need a bigger degree change then a couple degrees.